# python undetected chromedriver fail to run

Tags: python, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

I'm scrapping a website using selenium but I get detected all the time. I decided to use [Undetected chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver). But I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "undt.py", line 746, in <module>
    booter()
  File "undt.py", line 92, in booter
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=option)
  File "C:\Users\azureuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 414, in __init__
    close_fds=IS_POSIX,
  File "C:\Users\azureuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\azureuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1148, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Users\azureuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 555, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

My code is simple

```
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])
driver = uc.Chrome(options=option)
```

Note: I'm running python version 3.7.9 32bit

Comment: _but I get detected all the time_: Have you looked for a solution within Stack Overflow?

Comment: Post the URL to check.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I tried everything I could find; randomize useragents, adding user profil, proxies ...

Comment: @AbiSaran this is the website: https://tempail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, its working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://tempail.com/")
```

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Are you using options while launching chrome browser?

Comment: yes I am using them

Comment: Remove them and try, use the same exact code I posted.

Comment: I just did. Still getting the same error. I believe it has to do with the python version I am using.

Answer (score 0):

undetected-Chromedriver had issues on 32Bit Python running on 64Bit Windows. That should be resolved with the newest updates.